# How do I create an Or condition on a dictionary of elements in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

```
dict = {a:[1,2,3,4], b:[4,5,6]}
```

I would like to create a function func1 that takes in a dictionary as an argument

```
def func1(dict, elem1, elem2):
```

and use a simple way to essentially create the following if condition

```
if ((elem1 ==a and elem2 in dict[a]) or (elem1 == b and elem2 in dict[b]))
```

the dictionary can have multiple key-value entries

Answer (score 1):

```
def func1(a_dict, elem1, elem2):
    return elem2 in a_dict.get(elem1,[])
```

I guess?

would yeild the following

```
data = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[4,5,6]}

print(func1(data,'a',6)) #False
print(func1(data,'a',2)) #True
print(func1(data,'b',2)) #False
print(func1(data,'b',6)) #True
```

although im not sure what you expect if elem1 is not in the dictionary... this implementation just returns False